# Condition attribute in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In some project I found this part:

```
    <Grid cond:MaxWidth="if ADMIN '350' elif USER '200'">
```

This XAML file is used in many other projects and they all specified their own condition compilation symbols (ADMIN or USER). According to this, compilator (?) will put correct max width to grid.

In addition this XAML file is beginning with this comment:

```
    <!--#attr cond-->
```

and this is the only two places, where 'cond' attribute appears.

The project is compilable, but I get this warning every time:

> 'cond' is an undeclared prefix. Line 15, position 11. XML is not valid.

Is it possible to fix this warning? Where this 'cond' is defined? Where could I read about this feature?

Comment: We don't know. Probably you should check your references and see if there is a (third-party) library that specifies this.

Comment: You need to check if 'cond' namespace is been defined or not. Check this article: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/01/28/Using-Conditional-XAML-in-Universal-Windows-Apps.aspx

Comment: @Savaratkar that [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConditionalXAML/) mentioned in Diederik's post seems to use another syntax though. But it's worth a try.

Comment: @Bart ya, Diederik's post might be using some other library, but Sebrin might need to include in his namespace 'cond' with his lib.